# NSUserDefaults Not Saving Data. Limits?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have such a problem: the syntax of saving data in userDefaults is clear and was working everyday in app. Today i have such a problem that nothing is stored after synchronize. P.S i have no syntax error.

here is an example of saving and reading:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"StackOverflow"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And reading

```
BOOL stackOverflow = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"StackOverflow"];
```

I know information about mutableCopy but in this simple situation it's not needed.

So is there any limits for userDefaults? I am testing on real device and storage i have up to 50GB free. I know that userDefaults are stored in plist file which in critical situation could be 1MB but i even dont exceed 1kb :( ...

```
using latest xcode and latest iOS version on 6S.
```

Need Advice. Thanks For help.

Comment: have you debugged and checked what's saved in defaults? how are you testing this (timing is important).

Comment: the value is correct in debugger (i am testing with po [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"StackOverflow"]  and po [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]
)  value is correct. I have read information about terminating app (while terminated is little chance not to save data) but i tried all the ways.

Comment: Are the reading & writing happening on the same thread or different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after half hour morning work i find the solution and actually the problem. Case such as mine in 90% it is developers fault, so it was.

**I had more than 30 user defaults value's, in which for e.g 15 of them had `initWithSuitName` (Identifier), everything saved with identifier id was working well but saving value without it was broken because of preferance conflicts.**

*`Solution:` I replaced unnamed userDefaults with identifier and everything has fixed.*

> In Case of some problem with NSUserDefaults:

**NSUserDefaults -** is thread safe.

**Synchronize -** Saves data immediately

**Saving Data -** If app will terminate chance of losing data is 50%, after debug Stop button tapped is same scenario. P.S data lose will be 50% if it's not saved in right place.

**Debuging NSUserDefaults** - in debugger you can simply tipe `po [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]` and `po [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"KeyForSavedData"]`

**Shared Container Example** - if you want to share property for example  between app and extension you can simply type `appGroup` identifier inside `initWithSuitName:@"com.Example.ExampleAPP"`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before. I just remove the key before add it to new object.
Example

```
 [NSUSER removeObjectForKey:@"savedData"];
    [NSUSER setBool:YES forKey:@"savedData"];
    [NSUSER  synchronize];
```

Note:
    If you are used so many no of NSUSER then it act like ridicules. This is by my little experience.

Comment: I am using different data more then 10 tipes in this project, eveything is broken. Is this problem of device? I deleted app reseted privacy and content but bug still exists

Comment: No problem to the device. sometimes the nsuser does not read by the xcode. Its so very rare case by my experience when i was use 20 to 30 nsuser frequently. But keep it in your mind if you are not use that nsuser as long please remove it as soon as possible.